# Scrollable HTML Content in pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, scrollbar

I have a scrollable `div` in HTML.
I want to achieve scrolling in PDF.

How do I convert HTML to PDF and achieve this?
Is it possible to embed HTML code inside a PDF file?
If not, what are other ways to obtain a scrolling content inside a PDF file?

**Edit:**
I have Seen a pdf with scrollable content :  Snipp From pdf : 
[image: Here is Snipp from the Pdf]

How this is achieved ? Anyone

Comment: Imagine this: what would a scrollable `div` look like when printed on paper? Scrollable content in PDF is only possible when using an annotation (e.g. RichMedia, widget annotation for a choice field,...). It's NOT possible to have scrollable content inside the content stream of a page. You're making assumptions about PDF that are completely wrong.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie  : See my update to question.

Comment: That's an annotation, probably a widget annotation for a text field.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible to append html in pdf Using php TCPDF library, it also supports inline css but i am not sure if it supports overflow or not....but yes it is possible to embed HTML in pdf using TCPDF and is the advantage over FPDF...

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way for you to do that. A PDF viewer does not have a browser inside it, nor does it have a plug-in mechanism for you to embed something "foreign" inside the file.

Comment: See my update to question. I have seen a pdf with scrollable content in it.